# go lang construct map based on filter criteria

Tags: dictionary, go

I have below structures

```
type ModuleList []Module

type Module struct {
    Id                  string
    Items               []Item
    Env                 map[string]string
}

type Item struct {
    Id    string
    Host  string
}
```

I have a service which returns **ModuleList**; but I would like to create a function which can group **ModuleList** based on **Module** **Env** key value and return **map[string]ModuleList**  or **map[string]*Module**

Can i have any sample function which does this ?

I had tried doing this

```
appsByGroup := make(map[string]ModuleList)
    for _, app := range apps {
        if _, ok := app.Env["APP_GROUP"]; ok {
            appGroup := app.Env["APP_GROUP"]
            appsByGroup[appGroup] = app
        }
    }
```

; but not quite sure how to add element to an array

Comment: updated what i have done in inline

Comment: Removed my downvote and close flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group all the `Modules` by a `APP_GROUP` then you are pretty much correct. You are just not appending to the slice correctly:

```
appsByGroup := make(map[string]ModuleList)
for _, app := range apps {
    if _, ok := app.Env["APP_GROUP"]; ok {
        appGroup := app.Env["APP_GROUP"]
        // app is of type Module while in appsGroup map, each string
        // maps to a ModuleList, which is a slice of Modules.
        // Hence your original line
        // appsByGroup[appGroup] = app would not compile
        appsByGroup[appGroup] = append(appsByGroup[appGroup], app)
    }
}
```

Now you can access all the `Modules` (stored in a slice) in a group by using:

```
// returns slice of modules (as ModuleList) with
// Env["APP_GROUP"] == group
appGroups[group]
```